# Prove that if $n$ and $m$ are odd integers, then $n-m$ is an even integer. Proposed proof: $2k + 1 – 2j + 1 = 2$, so it is always odd.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove that if $n$ and $m$ are odd integers, then $n-m$ is an even integer.

---

Find the mistake in this proposed proof:

$2k + 1 – 2j + 1 = 2$, so it is always odd.

Comment: Why are you assuming that $k=j$? And why do you say that $2$ is "always odd"?

Comment: $(2k + 1) - (2j + 1) = 2k - 2j$, which is not necessarily equal to $2$, but it can be shown to be even with just one more step.

Comment: Did you say $2$ is odd???????

Comment: It is suppose to be find the mistake. Apologies. I am just confused on where to go.

Comment: This OP doesn't deserve to be downvoted. They, at least, tried showing their work. Downvoting for tone is bad form. @TohkiMilo, $2k + 1 - 2j + 1 = 2k - 2j = 2(k - j).$ What parity does $2(k - j)$ have? Is it odd or even? To answer the question, look up the definitions of "odd" and "even".

Comment: But there are two mistakes in that proposed proof. How do we choose between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the question has been modified to **find** the mistakes.

So if $n$ and $m$ are odd, we can let $n=2k+1$ and $m=2j+1$ for some integers $k$ and $j$.

Now $n-m=(2k+1)-(2j+1)=2(k-j) \neq 2k+1-2j+1 $, and hence it is **even** for all integers $k$ and $j$, not **odd**. Also note that $2$ is an **even** number, not **odd**.